# Function for iterating through all unique combinations of a matrix

Tags: python, function

I'm new to coding. I'm trying to write a function that creates a list of 4x1 matrices from my data where the last row is always zero. Each consecutive matrix exchanges one row for another so that each array is unique and no combinations of numbers are repeated.

```
# The array I'm using
[[-28.71703997]
[-20.3186618]
[-47.5926421]
[-24.42789423]
[-69.78148825]
[-42.91613279]
[0.0]]
```

I'm trying to make matrices using 1st 2nd and 3rd row, then the 1st 2nd and 4th row, then the 1st 2nd and 5th row and so on. Then move down to create matrices with the 2nd 3rd and 4th row, the 2nd 3rd and 5th row and so on. Can anyone help with this? I keep getting a NameError for 'j' and 'arrb'.
Here is my code:

```
# arr_e is the array of Free Energies that I'm trying to use and m is the length.

def EnergyArrays(arr_e, m):
    listn = []
    matrix = [[]]
    for i in range(m-2):
        for j in range(i, m-2):
            matrix = Matrix4x1(arr_e[i], arr_e[j+1], arr_e[j+2])
            listn.append(matrix)
    return listn

def Matrix4x1(arra, arrb, arrc):
    matrix = np.zeros([4,0], dtype=float)
    for i in range(4):
        if i == 0:
            matrix[i][j] = arra[j]
        if i == 1:
            matrix[i][j] = arrb[j]
        if i == 2:
            matrix[i][j] = arrc[j]

    return matrix
```

My expected output is a list of arrays:

```
[[-28.71703997]
[-20.3186618]
[-47.5926421]
[0.0]]

[[-28.71703997]
[-20.3186618]
[-24.42789423]
[0.0]]

[[-28.71703997]
[-20.3186618]
[-69.78148825]
[0.0]]

[[-28.71703997]
[-20.3186618]
[-42.91613279]
[0.0]]

[[-20.3186618]
[-47.5926421]
[-69.78148825]
[0.0]]

[[-20.3186618]
[-47.5926421]
[-42.91613279]
[0.0]]

[[-47.5926421]
[-24.42789423]
[-69.78148825]
[0.0]]

[[-47.5926421]
[-24.42789423]
[-42.91613279]
[0.0]]
```

etc, etc...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you please provide your expected output. It's difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: This can be done with [itertools.combinations()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).